# Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL value

Tags: php, oracle

I'm new to php & oracle and I'm trying to insert data from form into the database but following error occured.

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("OE"."CUSTOMERS"."CUST_LAST_NAME") in C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\newentries.php on line 39

Help me on how do I insert data into database.
Code is:

```
<?php

require_once('./dbinfo.inc.php');

session_start();


echo <<<EOD
  <body style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">

  <form action="newentries.php" method="POST">

    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"></p>

   <p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname"</p>

    <p>CustomerId: <input type = "text" name = "cust_id"></p>

    <p>Email ID: <input type = "text" name = "cust_email"></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  </body>

EOD;

if(!empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['cust_id']) && !empty($_POST['cust_email']))
{
    $c = oci_pconnect(ORA_CON_UN, ORA_CON_PW, ORA_CON_DB);

    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];

    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];

$id = $_POST['cust_id'];

    $email = $_POST['cust_email'];

    $stid = oci_parse($c, "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(CUSTOMER_ID,CUST_FIRST_NAME,CUST_LAST_NAME,CUST_EMAIL) VALUES(:id_bv,:fname_bv,:lname_bv,:email_bv)");

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':fname_bv', $fname);

  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':lname_bv', $lname);

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':id_bv', $id);

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':email_bv', $email);

    oci_execute($stid);
}   
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

[table in which I want to enter the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEyFd.png)

Comment: you are inserting a null value into one of the columns: primary key,  first name, last name.  Likely the primary key, do you have a trigger set up to insert it?

Comment: There is no trigger set up for insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your code:

```
$flname = $_POST['lastname'];
...
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':lname_bv', $lname);
```

Comment: @vaibhav That's not enough info for me to help. And you've now edited your question to remove the typo, but say that the error is fixed. So now your question is wrong...

Comment: @vaibhav Check the return value of `oci_execute`; it should be `true` to indicate the statement worked.  If it isn't, call [`oci_error($c)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) to find out what went wrong.

Comment: That error means a record already exists. Try inserting different values.  A simple Internet search would have told you this. This is the third distinct problem I've helped you with here and SO is not a support forum. I suggest you find a tutorial or take a class on web application development.